# How to remove arrow in new page in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I use a `pushNamedRoute(NewScreen.routeName)`then automatically added the back arrow button how to delete that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add `automaticallyImplyLeading: false`, into your Scaffold's Appbar

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like Balaji Ramadoss mention. But if you don't want the user to be able to navigate to the last page, then rather use `pushReplacementNamed(context, routename)`